# How do I exclude Node modules from the Netlify function bundle?

Tags: netlify, netlify-function

I have a Netlify function that uses Puppeteer to render PDFs. Specifically, `puppeteer-core` and `chrome-aws-lambda`. Between these two modules, the bundle size is almost exactly at the 50MB limit for a function (this limitation is from AWS Lambda which Netlify Functions use). So much so that importing the S3 client from the ask-sdk (version 3) package tips the scale and the function can no longer be deployed.

Lambda's already have the aws-sdk included by default so bundling the module is unnecessary. However, because it's being imported, Netlify's build step thinks it should be included.

How can I exclude a module(s) from the function bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `netlify.toml` there is an [undocumented](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/file-based-configuration/) option for `[functions]` called `ignored_node_modules` that lets you specify an array of Node modules to exclude from the bundle.

The following will ignore the modules across all functions.

```ini
[functions]
  ignored_node_modules = ["aws-sdk"]
```

Or you can target a specific function by name

```ini
[functions.render]
  ignored_node_modules = ["aws-sdk"]
```

Note that all Lambdas running Node (Even Node 16 LTS) are still using `aws-sdk` (version 2) and not `@aws-sdk` (version 3).

For anyone curious, I discovered this option [here](https://github.com/netlify/cli/blob/ed66573ed8e5cfa8c6b6a2cf612491b3e254c40b/src/lib/functions/config.js#L12) in the Netlify CLI source.